# How to place floating action button in bottom right in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I am trying to place a floating action button in the lower right corner of my app but it is placing it in the top left way off screen.

**Returned view:**

```
<View>
   <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPress} activeOpacity={.5} >
          <Image
              source={require('./assets/images/hamburger.png')}
              style={{ width: 30, height: 25,  marginLeft: 15}}
          />
      </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
   <FloatingAction style={styles.bottom}/>
</View>
```

**Styles:**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bottom: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 10,
    right:10
  },
});
```

My current view displays a header and a bottom tab view. I am able to place multiple FAB's in each tab screen but that produces an undesirable behavior. Thank you for any help.

**Edit:**
What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: Can you share some screenshots of what you got and what you need?

Comment: @DevAs updated, is that clear?

Comment: To debugging your styles try to add a background for Views you have, so add a bg to the parent view it will tell u what's spaces available and so on

Comment: @DevAS When I do that the Hamburger icon is highlighted, but that is the only change.

Comment: Try to add flex:1 to your parent view

Comment: So as @VolkanSahin45 said try it, if did not help increase the bottom value, but I think flex:1 enough

Comment: @DevAS none of those suggestions had any effect

Comment: Can you share ur code on snack.expo.io?

Comment: And try to remove flex:1 from styles.bottom. The idea is you should add your floating action button in the main area that fill whole screen.

Comment: Fair enough @VolkanSahin45

Comment: @DevAS here is the link https://snack.expo.io/@dahous1/nervous-chocolate

Comment: It's working fine! https://snack.expo.io/@anastely/nervous-chocolate

Comment: @DevAS I see it working on the snack you provided but it still isn't working with my device. Could my tabs be interfering with it?

Comment: Exactly, u can add the floating button inside every screen (public, friend, home)

Comment: @DevAS However when I do that I get the undesired result of the FAB moving with the screen, I want the button to be seperate from each screen as described here: https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/#behavior

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203405/discussion-between-devas-and-bjorn).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue was on adding `{ flex: 1, position: 'absolute',}` to the button style together. The parent component that covers all the phone screen would use `flex: 1`, your button component is the one that receives the style for the position.

Always creating a new component makes stuff easier to read and understand. So let's say you have a button component (`<FloatingButton/>`), you would do something like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import FloatingButton from './FloatingButton';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          I'm just a Text
        </Text>

        <FloatingButton 
          style={styles.floatinBtn}
          onPress={() => alert(`I'm being clicked!`)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  floatinBtn: {
    
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 10,
    right: 10,
  }
});
```

You will get this result:

[image]

This is the button component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default props => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress} style={props.style}>
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        width: 45,
        height: 45,
        borderRadius: 45,
      }}
    />
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Check the snack demo: https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/floating-btn

Answer (score 1):

```js
// this should occupy the whole screen
<View style={{flex:1}}>
   <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPress} activeOpacity={.5} >
          <Image
              source={require('./assets/images/hamburger.png')}
              style={{ width: 30, height: 25,  marginLeft: 15}}
          />
      </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
   <FloatingAction style={styles.bottom}/>
</View>
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bottom: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 10,
    right:10
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use that CSS in your code:

```
.floating-btn {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:10;
  right: 10;
}
```

That's it